# How to store collect tracking data in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I am using the [Collect Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_collect_code.htm&type=5) code from Analytics Builder to track user activity on my website. Using the audience builder I can see that the traffic is tracked, however in order for me to expose this data in Data Extensions I need to setup Personalisation Studio, more specifically a Catalog.

Is there a way around this? I don't need tracking on what items they've visited, just whether they have been on the website (and maybe what pages if its easy). I've tried downloading the sample catalog and uploading a copy with only one line in the upload but this gets rejected for having "Not enough data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this each webpage will need to exist in the catalog with a product code, and then you will want to track that product code in your collect code as item. This will then populate igo_views with each item they visited and you can join this to igo_productattribs to see what the url/page name is.

Comment: To list the whole catalog of pages for the website will take some time. Is there a quicker alternative at all? The pages are already tracked and visible in analytics studio, not sure why we need a catalog just to see it within DEs.

Comment: WAMA (Web and Mobile Analytics) doesn't push data to DE, Personalization builder does, but requires the items to exist in a catalog. iiwii ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How would I handle dynamic URLs using the catalog?

Comment: I would suggest streaming updates. Have you considered Google analytics?

Comment: We need to use the tracking data for a journey, when you say using google analytics do you mean just not using personalisation studio?